# Reading from embedded Neo4j (Blueprints) randomly returns null

Tags: scala, playframework, neo4j

I'm trying to resolve a problem with Neo4j and Blueprints. Adding vertices works OK as well as adding properties to them. But there is a problem when I'm trying to read vertices from database. They are all read - so number of them is OK, but they randomly does not have their properties and edges. Instead of them I'm getting nulls. What is very strange, when a Vertex once have null properties, another time it has there expected value. Im also using PlayFramework and on each refresh I'm adding 2 vertices with property (name: Jan, name; Adam). It looks like a problem with reading data from graph-embeded database. Has anyone had a similiar troubles? I'm attaching a listing with debug to show you better perspective to my problem.
Thanks in advance for every response ;)

```
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[2] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[2] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[3] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[4] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[6] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: null
[debug] application - v[6] name: null
[debug] application - v[7] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[8] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: null
[debug] application - v[6] name: null
[debug] application - v[7] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[8] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[9] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[10] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: null
[debug] application - v[6] name: null
[debug] application - v[7] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[8] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[9] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[10] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[11] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[12] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[6] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[7] name: null
[debug] application - v[8] name: null
[debug] application - v[9] name: null
[debug] application - v[10] name: null
[debug] application - v[11] name: null
[debug] application - v[12] name: null
[debug] application - v[13] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[14] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - -----------------------------------------------
[debug] application - v[1] name: null
[debug] application - v[2] name: null
[debug] application - v[3] name: null
[debug] application - v[4] name: null
[debug] application - v[5] name: null
[debug] application - v[6] name: null
[debug] application - v[7] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[8] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[9] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[10] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[11] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[12] name: Jan Nowak
[debug] application - v[13] name: null
[debug] application - v[14] name: null
[debug] application - v[15] name: Adam Kowalski
[debug] application - v[16] name: Jan Nowak
```

Comment: Is that in a simple single threaded application?

Comment: How do you structure your transactions? Perhaps you add them in one thread/tx and read them in another where they haven't been committed yet.

Comment: yes, that is a simple thread transaction; 
nodes are added in simple way:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki

Comment: Can you show up the code you use to list those vertices ? And list neo4j and blueprints versions ?

Comment: Probably it's because of play and its akka system behind. I think it starts several threads if necessary